# Getting the asp image url using a function from another CS

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have the following code in a class called **Users.aspx**:

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#GetImagePath("Icon1.jpg")%>'
```

In **Users.aspx.cs** I've implemented:

```
public string GetImagePath(string imgName)
{
    string Finalurl = "~/App_Themes/Default/Images/" + imgName;
    return Finalurl;
}
```

The thing is that I want to have the the **GetImagePath** function in a general helper class and use it from multiple places and not define it in every .aspx.cs file and have in the aspx classes something like:

```
<asp:Image ID="SomeImage" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#GeneralHelper.GetImagePath("Icon1.jpg")%>'
```

How can it be implemented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declare it static, the class and the function, as:

```
public static class GeneralHelper
{
  public static string GetImagePath(string imgName)
  {
    string Finalurl = "~/App_Themes/Default/Images/" + imgName;
    return Finalurl;
  }
}
```

You place it on a new file (GeneralHelper.cs), that ether you compile it and include it on your bin as dll, ether place it on the App_Code directory.

Comment: Thanks, I was just missing the "<%@ Import Namespace="Helpers" %>"